# Python 3.4 and virtual environment's pip

Tags: python3, pip

I create a new virtual env but pip is always the "global" one

```
$ python3 -m venv MyVenv
$ source Myvenv/bin/activate
(MyVenv)$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

and I don't know why.

I want to use the env's one... (I'm on Ubuntu 15.04)

edit: full $PATH of a `test` venv as required:

```
/home/doc/test/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by reinstalling ubuntu, i think i had screwed up python3 installation with some "apt-get" packages

Answer (score 0):

No repro.

```
$ python3 -m venv MyVenv
$ source MyVenv/bin/activate

(MyVenv) $ which pip
/home/oli/Desktop/MyVenv/bin/pip

(MyVenv) $ which pip3
/home/oli/Desktop/MyVenv/bin/pip3
```

I'd try again (honestly, those were the commands I used) but failing that, with most virtualenv-related things, if you call the binary directly, it'll use the right environment even without activating it.

In my case that looks like:

```
/home/oli/Desktop/MyVenv/bin/pip3 install Django
```

---

There is also a bug in ensurepip in Python 3 on 14.04 (and maybe newer versions) in that it's completely missing. [You can manually install it](https://askubuntu.com/a/628969/449). If you're hitting this, it might explain what you're seeing.

```
wget -qO- http://d.pr/f/YqS5+ \
| sudo tar xzf - -C $(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path[1])") --no-same-owner
```

Then recreate and reactivate your venv.

Comment: I tried the same thing on my vps (ubuntu 14.04), pip is always the global one...

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Is activate crashing out for some reason? Is your local bin in the `$PATH`? (run `echo $PATH`)

Comment: yes, local bin is in the venv $PATH, along with the venv's bin

Comment: Can you append the full output of `echo $PATH` to your question, please?

Comment: @Doc you can use `python -mpip`, to make sure that `pip` corresponds to `python` executable (virtualenv or not). Run `python3 -m ensurepip`, to make sure `pip` is available.

Comment: @Oli i edited with full path

Comment: Is there a `pip` in `/home/doc/test/bin`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That reminds me, there's a wopping great big bug in Python 3 on 14.04 in that ensurepip just doesn't exist. I've fixed mine (I've added to my answer) so that's why it works for me.

Comment: @Oli yes, pip is present in /home/doc/test/bin

Comment: `stat ~/test/bin/pip` if it's executable and readable by your user too (and the partition it's on doesn't have noexec) then we are dealing with something that is impossible. Your path will force the venv version to be picked first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after creating the virtual environment via

`python -m venv test1`

I moved the entire venv directory and then activated it.  Turns out moving the venv folder seems to break the venv's pip path.  I was able to reproduce by creating a new one and moving it again.

With the venv activated, if you run

`set | grep test1`

you can see the venv bin directory is added to the path.

So one solution is just create the venv exactly where you want it and don't move it. Or else modify the venv's `activate` shell script to change the `VIRTUAL_ENV` value.